# Connect python to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How can I Connect to MySQL but my database is not localhost ?

here my .env

```
FLASK_APP=run.py
FLASK_ENV=development

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=coba_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I try to change the host to

```
FLASK_APP=run.py
FLASK_ENV=development

DB_HOST=192.168.1.3
DB_DATABASE=coba_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Any errors? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlalchemy to connect with Mysql database using create engine command like below:
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(username, password,
server, port, database))

Comment: I wrote this 

```
class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
  DEBUG = True
  # SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'coba_db.db') #TODO
   
  
  HOST = str(os.environ.get("DB_HOST"))
  DATABASE = str(os.environ.get("DB_DATABASE"))
  USERNAME = str(os.environ.get("DB_USERNAME"))
  PASSWORD = str(os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"))
  
  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + '/' + DATABASE
  SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
  SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True 
```